# Reed RSS News Feeds with XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rss, schema

I am new on ios programming. To improve my ios skills, want to create a news app for iphone. Well firstly, I think that I can use RSS feed but i see some rss feeds are different each other..some rss feed has title keyword but some not..

That means, there is a schema for all. But If I want to create an app for 20 news website, how  can I handle this problem. I do not want to write different code for 20 different rss feed. for example..

in one rss feed, i can use

```
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
```

but in another one

```
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"url"];
```

so, this is not effective method. I dont know how programmers solved it. I think i should follow kind of NOSQL, for schemaless, but dont know in xcode how to do it.

Comment: why don't you check if string == nil and if so, try the other key name?

Comment: because there are many websites so many different keys.. how many "if  keyword" should I write? Then I was looking for schemeless struct but its OK now, I choose websites which have similar construct.

Comment: It is not that much as there has to be a standard. So, mostly, link for the feed is located in `/rdf:RDF/channel/link` or `/feed/link` or `/rss/channel/link` and you can determine the type by checking if the feed has RSS, ATOM or RDF format.